# Error: Specified cast is not valid (Asp net, c#, SQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IBPJNA2;Initial Catalog=GeometryFINAL;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader rdr;         
int intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"]; //error is here
String strSql = "SELECT iProductID FROM orderItemsTable WHERE iOrderNo = " + intOrderNo;
cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, con);
```

Comment: You want to set a break point at that error line, and see what is inside that Session Variable.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your `Session["sOrderNo"]` has a value on it. looks like it doesn't exist or value is not convertable to integer.

what you can do is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IBPJNA2;Initial Catalog=GeometryFINAL;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader rdr;
if (Session["sOrderNo"] != null)
{
   int intOrderNo = 0;
   bool result = Int32.TryParse(Session["sOrderNo"], out intOrderNo );
   if (result)
   {
      String strSql = "SELECT iProductID FROM orderItemsTable WHERE iOrderNo = " + intOrderNo;
      cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, con);  
   }
   else
   {
       //values are not convertable to integer....
   }
}
else
{
   //your session variable doesn't exist....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Session["sOrderNo"] doesn't exist, or not int type when you set

You need check before

```
int intOrderNo = 0;
if(Session["sOrderNo"]!=null)
{
  int.TryPasre(Session["sOrderNo"].ToString(), out intOrderNo); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of assigning the session value to the variable `orderno` , there might be two possible cases

1. `Session["sOrderNo"]` is not yet initialized
2. `Session["sOrderNo"]` doesn't contain any value .

so in order to handle these two cases best possible way is

```
int intOrderNo = 0;
if(Session["sOrderNo"]!=null)
{
  intOrderNo = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sOrderNo"]); 
}
```

Comment: This code can throw an exception as well, use `TryParse` instead.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins in wat away ? , `Convert.ToInt32` will not throw nullreference exception, and i'm handling the `existence` case .. so where can it might go wrong ?

Comment: Session["sOrderNo"] = "true";
intOrderNo = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sOrderNo"]);

Comment: Or this: public class OrderNo {}; Session["sOrderNo"] = new OrderNo(); intOrderNo = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sOrderNo"]);

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins what actually you are saying is just another way of representing ,

Comment: Both of those will throw an exception. Session["sOrderNo"] could be of any type and Convert.ToInt32 can throw an exception.